# "Shouldly" throwing ShouldAssertException instead of displaying results

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, assertion

I've installed via nuget package manager Nunit with NUnitTestAdapter and  [Shouldly extension](https://github.com/shouldly) which IMO is more readable then regular assertion in nunit.

But when it goes to run my tests, the assertion throws ShouldAssertException with proper description of assertion mismatch instead of displaying results in test explorer in Visual Studio 2015.

Sample code in C#:

```
[Test]
public void Charge_ShouldBeOneHundred_WhenCartContainsTwoProducts_WhichCostsFifty()
{
    // Arrange
    Item item = a(Item().withPrice(50.0).withQuantity(2));
    ItemCollection items = a(Items().withItem(item));
    ShoppingCart cart = a(Cart().withItems(items));

    // Act
    cart.Checkout();

    // Assert

    cart.Payment.Value.ShouldBe(100.0);
}
```

How can I make it display in test explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a contrived example shouldly displays the results correctly for me in my test explorer window for VS 2015

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldyExample()
    {
        var payment = 40.0;
        payment.ShouldBe(50.0);
    }
```

[image]

After you run your test what is displayed in the test explorer window?

Comment: There you have a [screenshoot](https://s31.postimg.org/ogj2y9h63/image.jpg) showing how It looks like on my side.

Comment: What happens if you keep continue the test after that point? e.g. press F5? The test should conclude and display the results in the test explorer window

Comment: Yep, ignoring exception solved the problem. Thanks for your help though.